# How to log in a user into Magento from a .NET web application

Tags: asp.net, magento, soap, single-sign-on

I'm developing an e-commerce product using Asp.Net and C#. I would like to use the checkout pages from Magento.

So I'm using Magento SOAP API in order to:

1. Create a product.
2. Create a customer.
3. Create a cart.
4. Call shoppingCartCustomerSet to associate the cart with the customer.
5. Add the product to the cart and then call shoppingCartProductMoveToCustomerQuote.

I've learned that in order for the call to shoppingCartProductMoveToCustomerQuote to work out, the customer need to be signed in. I would like to single sign on the customer and redirect to the cart page of Magento, and I'm looking for the an easy and elegant way to do it.

The options I can think of are:

1. Use OAuth to log in the customer to Magento, but in this scenario the customer will have to enter their password, which they don't even know... I guess I can try to populate it somehow, but I think there should be an easier way.
2. Use PHP code I found in a similar questions ([Magento customer login programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22485694/magento-customer-login-programmatically), [Log user into Magento programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416898/log-user-into-magento-programmatically)), and create my own SOAP API.

Can you suggest any other solution?

Comment: It looks like Magento provides WSDL. Generate proxy class from it and use it. Although you still need a credential to access SOAP methods.

Comment: That's what I'm doing. But I also want to redirect the user to Magento cart, and so I need a way to sign in the user without the user knowing they were signed into a different application.

Comment: If it is possible extend the API. It shouldn't be so hard especially that it looks like you need to redefine acl stuff only.
Prepopulating logn page doesn't sound good.